# how can get value from xml with namespace ns2

Tags: xml, parsing, xml-parsing, xml-namespaces

I am getting task status from my aplication using Rest API. Sometimes I'm getting response with "ns2:", sometimes I'm getting response without "ns2" as you can see below;

I can get task status with the following command when I get response without "ns2".

`var document = XMLManager.fromString(xmlstring);`

`TaskState  = document.getElementsByTagName("Task").item(0).getAttribute("status");`

But, if I get response with "ns2", I can't get task status. I'm getting the following error; **TypeError: Cannot call method "getAttribute" of null**

How can I get task status from both response ?

````
<Task xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/cloud/v1.5" xmlns:vmext="http://www.microsoft.com/cloud/extension/v1.5" xmlns:ovf="http://schemas.dmtf.org/ovf/envelope/1" xmlns:vssd="http://schemas.dmtf.org/wbem/wscim/1/cim-schema/2/CIM_VirtualSystemSettingData" xmlns:common="http://schemas.dmtf.org/wbem/wscim/1/common" xmlns:rasd="http://schemas.dmtf.org/wbem/wscim/1/cim-schema/2/CIM_ResourceAllocationSettingData" xmlns:vmw="http://www.microsoft.com/schema/ovf" xmlns:ovfenv="http://schemas.dmtf.org/ovf/environment/1" xmlns:ns9="http://www.microsoft.com/cloud/versions" status="queued" operation="Creating Group" operationName="vdcGroupCreate" serviceNamespace="com.microsoft.cloud" startTime="2022-11-29T12:12:14.226+03:00" expiryTime="2022-12-29T12:12:14.226+03:00" cancelRequested="false" name="task" id="urn:cloud:task:4af7626c-29f2-45f8-bc85-f1017433bec1" href="https://domain.domain.com/api/task/4af7626c-29f2-45f8-bc85-f1017433bec1" type="application/vnd.microsoft.cloud.task+xml">
    <Link rel="edit" href="https://domain.domain.com/api/task/4af7626c-29f2-45f8-bc85-f1017433bec1" type="application/vnd.microsoft.cloud.task+xml" name="task"/>
    <Link rel="edit" href="https://domain.domain.com/api/task/4af7626c-29f2-45f8-bc85-f1017433bec1" type="application/vnd.microsoft.cloud.task+json" name="task"/>
    <Owner href="" id="urn:cloud:vdcGroup:215982ef-a837-47ba-b25f-915140584c98" type="application/json" name="test-DCG-DEFAULT"/>
    <User href="https://domain.domain.com/api/admin/user/58b3a41b-1e9a-4a63-8ac3-fb26c50a78bb" id="urn:cloud:user:58b3a41b-1e9a-4a63-8ac3-fb26c50a78bb" type="application/vnd.microsoft.admin.user+xml" name="dev-svc-vro"/>
    <Organization href="https://domain.domain.com/api/org/a93c9db9-7471-3192-8d09-a8f7eeda85f9" id="urn:cloud:org:a93c9db9-7471-3192-8d09-a8f7eeda85f9" type="application/vnd.microsoft.cloud.org+xml" name="System"/>
    <Details></Details>
    <VcTaskList/>
</Task> ```


--------------------------------------------


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ns2:Task xmlns:ovf="http://schemas.dmtf.org/ovf/envelope/1" xmlns:ns2="http://www.microsoft.com/cloud/v1.5" xmlns:vmext="http://www.microsoft.com/cloud/extension/v1.5" xmlns:vssd="http://schemas.dmtf.org/wbem/wscim/1/cim-schema/2/CIM_VirtualSystemSettingData" xmlns:common="http://schemas.dmtf.org/wbem/wscim/1/common" xmlns:rasd="http://schemas.dmtf.org/wbem/wscim/1/cim-schema/2/CIM_ResourceAllocationSettingData" xmlns:vmw="http://www.microsoft.com/schema/ovf" xmlns:ovfenv="http://schemas.dmtf.org/ovf/environment/1" xmlns:ns9="http://www.microsoft.com/cloud/versions" status="queued" operation="Creating Group" operationName="vdcGroupCreate" serviceNamespace="com.microsoft.cloud" startTime="2023-01-25T15:09:09.716Z" expiryTime="2023-02-24T15:09:09.716Z" cancelRequested="false" name="task" id="urn:cloud:task:7b3b217d-e618-48b6-a7c5-d51c96f41b14" href="https://demo.domain.com/api/task/7b3b217d-e618-48b6-a7c5-d51c96f41b14" type="application/vnd.microsoft.cloud.task+xml">
    <ns2:Link rel="edit" href="https://demo.domain.com/api/task/7b3b217d-e618-48b6-a7c5-d51c96f41b14" type="application/vnd.microsoft.cloud.task+xml" name="task"/>
    <ns2:Link rel="edit" href="https://demo.domain.com/api/task/7b3b217d-e618-48b6-a7c5-d51c96f41b14" type="application/vnd.microsoft.cloud.task+json" name="task"/>
    <ns2:Owner href="" id="urn:cloud:vdcGroup:356a425f-b334-416a-9f1a-2b1c72228588" type="application/json" name="1463341310test3-DCG-DEFAULT"/>
    <ns2:User href="https://demo.domain.com/api/admin/user/fb6f0924-11b7-40d3-bed4-7a582ba8b529" id="urn:cloud:user:fb6f0924-11b7-40d3-bed4-7a582ba8b529" type="application/vnd.microsoft.admin.user+xml" name="prod-svc-vro"/>
    <ns2:Organization href="https://demo.domain.com/api/org/a93c9db9-7471-3192-8d09-a8f7eeda85f9" id="urn:cloud:org:a93c9db9-7471-3192-8d09-a8f7eeda85f9" type="application/vnd.microsoft.cloud.org+xml" name="System"/>
    <ns2:Details></ns2:Details>
    <ns2:VcTaskList/>
</ns2:Task>```
````

Comment: Please tag your specific programming language.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
TaskState
```

to

```
document.getElementsByTagNameNS("http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml",
      "ns2:task"
    )[0].getAttribute('status')
```

and see if it works.